# How to iterate over my postlist to display tags from taggit?

Tags: python, django, loops

I want to iterate over my postlist, to show on click all the posts with the same tag.
I want them to display at the index.html .
I understand the function, but i don´t know how to implement it into my template.

My views.py

```
    from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

def tag(request, slug):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"post_list": posts, "tag": tag})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

My template

```
 <header class="masthead" >
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="site-heading">
                    <h5 class=" site-heading mt-3"> Erfolgreiche Problemlösungen in der Programmierung, Linux und Windows</h5>
                    <p class="texthead">
                    </p>
                </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              </header>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

              <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
              <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
              {% for post in post_list %}
                <div class="card mb-4" >
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on | date:"d M Y"}} | Tag:
                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                            <a class="mycardtext" href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
                        {% empty %}
                          None
                        {% endfor %}
                        </p>

                        <p class="card-text">{{post.content|truncatewords:25|safe}}</p>
                        <div><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}"
                        class="btn btn-danger">Weiterlesen</a></h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
                {% block sidebar %}
                {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
                {% endblock sidebar %}
            </div>
        </div>
{%endblock%}
```

My Urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView



favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/UrosDobricic/mysite/static/favicon.png', permanent=True)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path("tag/<slug:slug>/", views.tag, name='tag'),

]
```

The tags are shown on the blog. My problem is, that i created in the views.py this post_list = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag), but in my template i have no posts definded.
So when i define the part :{% for tag in post.tags.all %} into to {% for tag in post_list.tags.all %}, it shows me "NONE" at my blog.
I can´t get the right solution, so i wanted to ask if somebody has a tip for me.
Generally this means that i have to display

{% for tags in post_list %}

{{ tags }}

{% endfor %}

Or am I wrong?
If somebody can answer with an example based on my files, that would be great.

Comment: Why do you then call your context variable `posts` and not `post_list`?

Comment: I tried that also, but the same thing happens

Comment: In your template you have {% for post in post_list %} and *inside* of that {% for tag in post.tags %}. That just works as long as post_list is defined (whether it's the list of *all* posts or just the filtered posts). Don't change it and it should work. Just change your view to return `{"post_list": posts}`.

Comment: Without the tag:tag?

Comment: or with if you use it in your template, I left it out because it's not relevant to the question. Currently you're not using it in your template but maybe you do want to so you can show to the user which tag they selected.

Comment: Nope, the same thing is happening. It shows the tags on my site, but it don´t filter with tags. I updated the file´s above with the info´s you gave me so you can see my current status.

Comment: Wait, your code for the `tag()` view is really exactly as you show? You are receiving a `slug` but filtering with `tag`. Thought this was just a typo from you here on SO.

Comment: Yes, i copied my code.
I did that because if i insert in tag() tag, and not slug, then i get this error:
tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'
Or do i have to change tag() with slug()?

Comment: yes, correct, you have to `def tag(request, slug):` because probably in your urls.py you use `slug` as the parameter. but then you have to use `slug` in your filter and context, not `tag`. `tag` is the view function itself.

Comment: I updated the files above with my Urls.py, so you can see it also.
I´m using 'tag' in Urls.py.
Can you give me an example how i have to redifine everything?
Actually i don´t get the point of my problem. :D

Comment: `slug` is the variable. so you need to do `filter(tags__slug=slug)`. And `{'tag': slug}`. Not `tag`. Please learn python.

Comment: Yeah man, thats it.
Thanks a lot.